# Which is correct token program address

Tags: solana-program, program, spl-token-program

I'm from ETH coming to SOL. But I noticed in this [article](https://www.0xdev.co/how-to-transfer-tokens-on-solana-javascript/), the smart contract address (token program address) is this way - https://nimb.ws/sIxWM7

But here the address starts with the word "Token" like - https://nimb.ws/UT6PrM

So which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one that starts `Token` is the Token program, which is a Solana program that can be used to create/mint/transfer/etc. SPL tokens.

The one in your first screenshot (and the one labeled 'Mint' in your second screenshot) is a particular token that has been created using that program. So they're different things, and I'm not too sure which you're asking for.

- If you want to interact with a specific token, it's the one in your first screenshot
- If you want to interact with the Token program, it's the one in your second screenshot

Comment: Could you explain, if I want to transfer 1 USDC to another wallet, which address should I use? I don't understand what "interact with a specific token" means. I thought tokens are all controlled by a token program (like USDC token is controlled by USDC token program) so our code just sends instructions to token program to send 1 USDC to someone. But here, do I talk to the USDC token itself?

Comment: You need to use the associated token account, which gives you a USDC address for yourself and for the recipient. See this cookbook example (view the full source code to see where the token accounts come from): https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-send-spl-tokens